# Visual Studio's Git graph is showing the wrong operation

Tags: git, visual-studio, bitbucket

Visual Studio 2022's integrated Git features have always been acting strangely with my Bitbucket repository, and I've always wondered why, but it hasn't ever actually interrupted my team's workflow. Recently, however, a branch merge has seemingly gone awry. Despite using the `Merge 'feature' into 'main'` functionality that VS'22 provides, the commit graph does not seem to reflect a standard merge (it almost resembles a rebase(?) instead).

Helpfully, Bitbucket shows the "real" commit graph (how I expected it to appear). Here it is side-by-side with Visual Studio's approximation:

[image: Screenshot of the different commit graphs]

Bitbucket's graph (left) shows the feature being branched from main, getting several commits, and then being merged back into main. Visual Studio (right) seemingly depicts a rewritten history, wherein all commits were on a separate branch until the feature branch, which seems to have all of the commits from main put at the end of it.

I'm not super familiar with the intricacies of Git, but I know that this is not how a relatively run-of-the-mill merge should look. I wouldn't be worried about this if it weren't for Visual Studio recognizing parent vs child commits "backwards" like this, which has me concerned that things like branch heads are now in the wrong place or something. The only thing I did differently this time compared to past merges was unchecking the "automatically commit if no conflicts are found" checkbox in VS after starting the merge.

Will this visual discrepancy have any functional impact my repository?

Comment: Looks like a simple difference between display styles. The highlighted (in blue) branch in the VS graph doesn't indicate that the branch "*is now main*", it just highlights it to focus the graph around it since the branch is currently checked out. There's technically no main branch in git, every branch is optional and all are just pointers. The "main" branch (whatever name it has) is just a given role in a workflow, but it's beyond git scope.

Comment: @RomainValeri Thanks for the information, I do appreciate it, but I suppose my phrasing may have been misleading (since edited). Is there any reason that the commit for the merge would be on the 'feature' branch rather than the 'main' branch when the merge operation went in the opposite direction?

Comment: Are you assuming that the big (orange) circle in bitbucket's graph means "merge commit"? Because it doesn't. Merge commits have more than one parent, and the only merge commit on the graph is the last (small) circle, the uppermost. I'm not sure why it's featured as a big dot, but I'd suppose it's because it's the last commit on the currently displayed branch.

Comment: But more importantly : "*Will this visual discrepancy have any functional impact my repository?*" -> No.

Comment: I definitely was making that assumption, thanks for the answer!